# Using iTunes, can I write all of the metadata into ID3 tags?

Tags: windows, itunes, mp3, id3

I'm not sure, but this may be part of the organization of my library. Currently, all of my music is properly sorted and indexed with accurate data. I want to make sure that this is written to the ID3 tags within each of the files. Can this be done, if it isn't done already? If not, is there an application that can read my iTunes metadata and write it into ID3 tags within my MP3s?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am pretty sure that iTunes automatically writes metadata about your files into the ID3 tags of the individual files. Besides, this data is carried over to iPods from within the files, and is kept when you drag the files out of iTunes and onto your desktop. I also managed to Google an article that says that editing iTunes metadata directly edits the ID3 tags. You're alright.

EDIT: Actually, I just learned there is a "Convert ID3 Tags" option in this "Advanced" menu of iTunes. You may want to try this, [this](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1868?viewlocale=en_US) Apple support page says it can help with the compatibility of your metadata.

Comment: OK. A few files weren't updated yet. Maybe iTunes is writing them in the background and hasn't gotten there yet as I was doing a lot of batch updating.

Comment: Try the Convert ID3 Tags option I just described in an edit of my post to be sure.

Comment: What I can say for sure is that iTunes is not writing the cover art into the ID3 tags, even if you tell i to "Convert ID3 Tags".

Comment: @BetaRide Not those downloaded from the iTunes Store, but all copy/paste and file drag 'n' drops are written to the files. (you can embed the iTunes store artwork by doing a copy-paste over itself)

Answer (score 0):

it used to but for some reason it stopped doing that now, the only way around it i found was to highlight all the tracks on my ipod and then edit an unused field, for instance bpm. then i put "120" in under bpm or something and then hit ok and it resends all id3 data to the tracks. you can always repeat the process afterwards, this time deleting the bpm data you entered.

it takes a while though but at least it means you don't have a bunch of files on your ipod with missing tags.